# Match string plus any non-whitespace character and insert whitespace

Tags: regex, string, replace, sed

I'm trying to match and replace a string in a lot of files.

String to search for:

```
</ANON>[any non-whitespace char], e.g. "</ANON>." or "</ANON>)"
```

I want to stick a whitespace in between the tag and the non-whitespace char.

I have tried to do it with sed using something like:

```
sed -i -e 's/<\/ANON>/S/<\/ANON> /S/g'
```

but alas, that doesn't work.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: Use \S instead of /S to represent a non-space character

Comment: The same as the input with a whitespace betweeen the tag and the non-whitespace char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sed -i -e 's|\(</ANON>\)\([^[:space:]]\)|\1 \2|g' file
```

It's not Perl and you can't use \S for non-whitespace characters. Also you should capture groups and use them in replacement part. Also you can't use /S because 1) it's wrong 2) slash used by sed for separating parts with pattern, replacement and flags.

P.S. Or you can use Perl if you like:

```
perl -p -i -e 's|(</ANON>)(\S)|$1 $2|g' file
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick except for a bunch of . , ) and numbers.

Comment: Okay, I have no clue why, but running the perl command a few times eventually caught all of them. Thanks a lot, mate.

Comment: Probably because you have more than one pattern in one line. To replace all of them just add `g` modifier (I've update my answer)